# Float value in Indigojs Bootstrap spinner

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a website, and I would use the [indigojs bootstrap spinner](https://github.com/indigojs/bootstrap-spinner). However, when using it, it's not possible to have a float step. I would like to have 0.1 value step on my input.

Could you help me to set options or modify the Javascript library to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set some defaults for the spinner.  The line you really need is `precision: 1`.  See below.

```
Spinner.DEFAULTS = {
  step: 0.1,
  min: 0,
  max: Infinity,
  precision: 1, // This fixes it
  strict: true
}
```